# GetProperty() returns null

Tags: c#, reflection

My Problem: I have 5 properties I need to set and the code for each is identical except for a couple parameters.  So rather than writing repeating code for each, I wanted to try reflection to set the values for all the parameters.

The properties are in the same class this code is running in, for example:

```
public MyClass
{
    public string? L1Value { get; set; }
    public string? L2Value { get; set; }
    public string? L3Value { get; set; }
    public string? L4Value { get; set; }
    public string? L5Value { get; set; }

    public void MethodToGetProperty()
    {
        var result = GetType().GetPropterty(L1Value);
    }
}
```

**In my actual code, I have a FOR loop that will dynamically create the parameter string name.  However, I have to get this `GetProperties()` to work.

`GetProperty(L1Value)` is returning null. I used `GetType().GetProperties()` and I see all the properties and L1Value has a value.

The questions in Stackoverflow I found all point to either 1) it was a field, not a property (no getter or setter) or 2) the access modifier was incorrect or missing.  Neither of these apply here.

[image]

I appreciate any suggestions you have.

Comment: You’re passing the value of the property, the method expects the name

Comment: You need, for example, `.GetProperty(nameof(L1Value))`

Comment: I'm assuming that your properties are _a lot_ more complicated than the auto-properties you are showing.  Anyone who wants to access your properties just needs to refer to them by name: `var x = new MyClass; var result = x.L1Value;`

Comment: Yes @Flydog57 it is.  I just didn't want to muddy the question.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `GetProperty` method you need to pass in the name of the property you want. For example:

```
var result = GetType().GetProperty("L1Value");
```

Or:

```
var result = GetType().GetProperty(nameof(L1Value));
```

Note this only give you the `PropertyInfo` object, so if you want the actual value, you will need to do this:

```
var value = result.GetValue(this);
```

Comment: a string!  ugh.  Thanks @DavidG

Comment: Reflection works in strings and objects - nothing type-ish, just strings and objects.  Powerful, yet frustrating.

Comment: @Flydog57 What do you mean? Reflection works fine for any type.

Comment: But, accessing a property (or a method, or a field, or...) requires the name as a string.  When you finish the access, what you get is a strongly-typed object, but whose return type is `object`.  You can't tell me that you've never gotten through reflecting something and mumbled "damn, I've gotten what I want, but it's an `object` - now what?"